# See permissions of all intermediate directories of a path?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Is there any single command to see the file/directory permissions of all the intermediate directories of a path?

Comment: ls -l /path doesnt work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of one such command, but it is almost 30 years old although it still works fine.  It should be rewritten in sh or perl, but this works:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
# pup - print all dir perms from here up to root

if ( $#argv == 0 ) then
        set args = ( $cwd )
else
        set args = ( $argv )
endif

@ mult = ( $#argv > 1 )

foreach dir ( $args )
        if ( $mult ) echo "${dir}:"
        loop:
                if ( "$dir" == '' ) set dir = '/'
                ls -lLd "$dir"
                if ( "$dir" == '/' ) goto next_for
                set dir = ( `echo "$dir" | sed 's;/[^/]*$;;'` )
                goto loop
next_for:
end
```

And here is an example of running it:

```
% pup /usr/src/usr.bin/vi/vi
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wsrc  1024 May 29  2008 /usr/src/usr.bin/vi/vi
drwxr-xr-x  13 root  wsrc  512 Aug  7  2008 /usr/src/usr.bin/vi
drwxr-xr-x  229 root  wsrc  4096 Aug  7  2008 /usr/src/usr.bin
drwxrwxr-x  18 root  wsrc  512 Aug  7  2008 /usr/src
drwxr-xr-x  22 root  wheel  512 Jan 28  2010 /usr
drwxr-xr-x  21 root  wheel  1024 Aug 23  2010 /
```

It default to the cwd.  Yes, the output is not pretty.  If I get motivated this morning, maybe I’ll rewrite it.

---

## EDIT

Here’s a rewrite that uses your system `ls` program.  It has advantages in how it deals with symlinks:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    
use strict;
use warnings;

use Cwd                qw( getcwd   abs_path );
use File::Basename      qw( dirname  );

sub ls { 0 == system("ls", "-lid", @_) }

@ARGV = getcwd() unless @ARGV;

for my $path (@ARGV) {
    if (-l $path) {
        ls($path);
        $path = abs_path($path);
    }
    while (ls($path) && $path !~ m{ \A /+ \z }x) {
        $path = dirname(abs_path($path));
    }
}

exit;
```

But I really hate the way `ls` formats things.  For example:

```
chthon(tchrist)% pup1 /dev/null /dev/zero /dev/tty /dev/stdin /dev/fd/0 ~ Mail
79283 crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel    2,   2 Nov  7 07:53 /dev/null
77953 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  22016 Oct 17 21:15 /dev
2 drwxr-xr-x  21 root  wheel  1024 Aug 23  2010 /
79284 crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel    2,  12 Oct 25  2008 /dev/zero
77953 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  22016 Oct 17 21:15 /dev
2 drwxr-xr-x  21 root  wheel  1024 Aug 23  2010 /
79280 crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel    1,   0 Nov  4 15:17 /dev/tty
77953 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  22016 Oct 17 21:15 /dev
2 drwxr-xr-x  21 root  wheel  1024 Aug 23  2010 /
79285 crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   22,   0 Oct 25  2008 /dev/stdin
77953 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  22016 Oct 17 21:15 /dev
2 drwxr-xr-x  21 root  wheel  1024 Aug 23  2010 /
79308 crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   22,   0 Oct 25  2008 /dev/fd/0
77954 dr-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  1024 Oct 25  2008 /dev/fd
77953 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  22016 Oct 17 21:15 /dev
2 drwxr-xr-x  21 root  wheel  1024 Aug 23  2010 /
1143296 drwxr-xr-x  197 tchrist  wheel  48128 Nov  7 07:53 /home/tchrist
2 drwxr-xr-x  15 root  wheel  512 Aug 12  2008 /home
2 drwxr-xr-x  21 root  wheel  1024 Aug 23  2010 /
1146538 lrwx------  1 root  wheel  5 Oct 23  2008 Mail -> /mail
2 drwxr-xr-x  134 tchrist  wheel  5120 Nov  7 07:43 /mail
2 drwxr-xr-x  21 root  wheel  1024 Aug 23  2010 /
```

See what I mean?  So here’s one that’s entirely built-in.

Took me forever to track down the major/minor macros, since the ls routine I stole from `find2perl`.  It probably won’t do these right on other systems than the ones I test for.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $USE_SHELL_LS_PROGRAM = 0;

use Cwd                qw( getcwd   abs_path );
use File::Basename      qw( dirname  );

@ARGV = getcwd() unless @ARGV;

*ls = $USE_SHELL_LS_PROGRAM ? \&your_ls : \&my_ls;

for my $path (@ARGV) {
    if (-l $path) { 
        ls($path);
        $path = abs_path($path);
    }
    while (ls($path) && $path !~ m{ \A /+ \z }x) { 
        $path = dirname(abs_path($path));
    }
} 

exit;

########

sub your_ls {
    0 == system("ls", "-lid", @_);
} 

sub my_ls {

    use POSIX           qw( strftime );

    my $name = shift();

    my @rwx = qw(--- --x -w- -wx r-- r-x rw- rwx);

    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
        $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = CORE::lstat($name) 
    or do {
        printf STDERR "$0: cannot lstat $name: $!\n";
        return 0;
    };

    my $pname = $name;

    $blocks
        or $blocks = int(($size + 1023) / 1024);

    my $perms = $rwx[$mode & 7];
    $mode >>= 3;
    $perms = $rwx[$mode & 7] . $perms;
    $mode >>= 3;
    $perms = $rwx[$mode & 7] . $perms;
    substr($perms, 2, 1) =~ tr/-x/Ss/ if -u _;
    substr($perms, 5, 1) =~ tr/-x/Ss/ if -g _;
    substr($perms, 8, 1) =~ tr/-x/Tt/ if -k _;
    if    (-f _) { $perms = '-' . $perms; }
    elsif (-d _) { $perms = 'd' . $perms; }
    elsif (-l _) { $perms = 'l' . $perms; $pname .= ' -> ' . readlink($name); }
    elsif (-c _) { $perms = 'c' . $perms; $size = sizemm($rdev); }
    elsif (-b _) { $perms = 'b' . $perms; $size = sizemm($rdev); }
    elsif (-p _) { $perms = 'p' . $perms; }
    elsif (-S _) { $perms = 's' . $perms; }
    else         { $perms = '?' . $perms; }

    printf "%9u %-10s %4d %-8s %-8s %8s %s %s\n",
            $ino,
                $perms,
                      $nlink,
                          user($uid),
                               group($gid),
                                    $size,
                                       strftime("%F %T", localtime $mtime),
                                            $pname;

    return 1;

}

sub sizemm {
    my $dev = shift;

    # these are almost always wrong:
    my $major = ($dev >> 8) & 0xff;
    my $minor = $dev & 0xff;

    # now fix the ones we know how to
    for ($^O) {

        if (/openbsd/) { 
            $major = ($dev >> 8) & 0xff;
            $minor = ($dev & 0xff) | (($dev & 0xffff0000) >> 8);
        }

        if (/darwin/) { 
            $major = ($dev >> 24) & 0xff;
            $minor = $dev & 0xffffff;
        }

        if (/solaris/) {
            $major = ($dev >> 18) & 0x3fff;
            $minor = $dev & 0x3ffff;
        }

        if (/linux/) {
            $major = (($dev >> 8) & 0xfff) | (($dev >> 32) & ~0xfff);
            $minor = ($dev & 0xff) | (($dev >> 12) & ~0xff);
        } 

    } 

    return sprintf("%3d, %3d", $major, $minor);

}

# cache user number to name conversions
sub user {
    use User::pwent;
    my $uid = shift;
    our %user;
    $user{$uid} = getpwuid($uid)->name || "#$uid"
        unless defined $user{$uid};
    return $user{$uid};
}

# cache group number to name conversions
sub group {
    use User::grent;
    my $gid = shift;
    our %group;
    $group{$gid} = getgrgid($gid)->name || "#$gid"
        unless defined $group{$gid};
    return $group{$gid};
}
```

For example:

```
chthon(tchrist)% pup2 /dev/null /dev/zero /dev/tty /dev/stdin /dev/fd/0 ~ Mail
    79283 crw-rw-rw-    1 root     wheel      2,   2 2011-11-07 07:34:47 /dev/null
    77953 drwxr-xr-x    3 root     wheel       22016 2011-10-17 21:15:55 /dev
        2 drwxr-xr-x   21 root     wheel        1024 2010-08-23 11:43:46 /
    79284 crw-rw-rw-    1 root     wheel      2,  12 2008-10-25 08:03:50 /dev/zero
    77953 drwxr-xr-x    3 root     wheel       22016 2011-10-17 21:15:55 /dev
        2 drwxr-xr-x   21 root     wheel        1024 2010-08-23 11:43:46 /
    79280 crw-rw-rw-    1 root     wheel      1,   0 2011-11-04 15:17:35 /dev/tty
    77953 drwxr-xr-x    3 root     wheel       22016 2011-10-17 21:15:55 /dev
        2 drwxr-xr-x   21 root     wheel        1024 2010-08-23 11:43:46 /
    79285 crw-rw-rw-    1 root     wheel     22,   0 2008-10-25 08:03:50 /dev/stdin
    77953 drwxr-xr-x    3 root     wheel       22016 2011-10-17 21:15:55 /dev
        2 drwxr-xr-x   21 root     wheel        1024 2010-08-23 11:43:46 /
    79308 crw-rw-rw-    1 root     wheel     22,   0 2008-10-25 08:03:51 /dev/fd/0
    77954 dr-xr-xr-x    2 root     wheel        1024 2008-10-25 08:03:51 /dev/fd
    77953 drwxr-xr-x    3 root     wheel       22016 2011-10-17 21:15:55 /dev
        2 drwxr-xr-x   21 root     wheel        1024 2010-08-23 11:43:46 /
  1143296 drwxr-xr-x  197 tchrist  wheel       48128 2011-11-07 04:16:49 .
        2 drwxr-xr-x   15 root     wheel         512 2008-08-12 16:51:23 /home
        2 drwxr-xr-x   21 root     wheel        1024 2010-08-23 11:43:46 /
  1146538 lrwx------    1 root     wheel           5 2008-10-23 14:50:24 Mail -> /mail
        2 drwxr-xr-x  134 tchrist  wheel        5120 2011-11-07 07:43:59 /mail
        2 drwxr-xr-x   21 root     wheel        1024 2010-08-23 11:43:46 /
```

Comment: Why is it called `pup`? By analogy to `dd`?

Comment: That's ironic.  The first instinct a person has on seeing this is to post a link to http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt (is there a more canonical link?).  I admit some surprise that this was posted by tchrist!

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Like *tell* me about it already. :( It was written in 1983 before I had taken up the holy war against csh. I see at least one bug in it, in that it doesn’t quote the backtick assignment. I think there are probably better links, but I don’t know about canon. Try [this one](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

Comment: I took the liberty of making a [bashy version](http://paste.linuxassist.net/215801), because even this much csh gives me hives. The behavior is the same except that it handles spaces correctly. A fancier version which also fixes the relative path infinite loop bug [is here](http://paste.linuxassist.net/215801).

Comment: Oops, second link above was the same as the first. Should have been [to here](http://paste.linuxassist.net/215800). Just for symmetry, [here's another one](http://paste.linuxassist.net/215803) that works with posix sh. Rant: I hate `stat` and how its formatting options are all non-standard. Can't get decent permissions out of `find` (`-printf` not standard) or `stat` (`-c`? `-f`? nothing?) and `ls` is just so inconsistent you can't even talk to it. Seems like `ls -lLd` really is the most reliable way to list permissions )-:

Comment: Would the anonymous markerdowner please look at the rewrites?

Comment: @larsmans I called it pup because it prints everything up.  No, it doesn't make a lot of sense but it is easy to type.

Answer (score 5):

You can run this code :

```
lsd() { local v="$1"; while :; do v="${v%/*}"; [[ "$v" && ! -f "$v" ]] || break; ls -ld "$v"; done; }


lsd /usr/share/doc/acl/README
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 14 mai   12:28 /usr/share/doc/acl/
drwxr-xr-x 145 root root 4096  4 nov.  06:23 /usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x 263 root root 12288  4 nov.  06:23 /usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 28 oct.  22:47 /usr/
```

**Edit:** added local keyword

**Edit2:** The last item error is resolved

Comment: I don't like the camelCase name one bit, and I don't like the way it resets a global variable, but +1 for the oneliner `sh` magic.

Comment: @larsmans Indeed, the command violates the v7 rules of shell command names, in which they are all lowercase and very short to type, at 8 or fewer characters.  The only exception I can quickly think of is `MAKEDEV`.

Comment: You can put the name you want, it's not predifined or such ;) For the global, you can add local to the loop...

Comment: -1 the last iteration always throws the error: `ls: : No such file or directory`, because `v` is empty. You also have to make sure you add a / to the last directory or it will be missed. e.g. `getPermForDirs /var/tmp` prints `drwxr-xr-x  40 root root 4096 Nov  6 05:09 /var/
ls: : No such file or directory`

Comment: Cool, but wouldn't it be nice to use `"\`readlink -f $1\`"` instead of just plain `"$1"`? Then you would be able to use give the filename with or without path.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple while-loop which does the job:

```
f="$PWD"
while [ "$f" != "/" ]
do
    ls -ld "$f"
    f=$(dirname "$f")
done
```

Comment: There’s some weird thing on Linux where you can find yourself at a root of "//".  Don’t remember how that works, though.

Comment: @tchrist: AFAIK no one uses it on any current Unix, so it's just treated the same as /. In this case I think listing / twice or listing // once would both be acceptable. That said, any use of // for / is probably not future proof.

Answer (score 2):

On linux, the `util-linux` package contains the `namei` command.

```sh
$ namei -l /full/path/to/file
```

Example:

```sh
$ namei -l /var/lib/systemd/catalog/database
f: /var/lib/systemd/catalog/database
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root var
drwxr-xr-x root root lib
drwxr-xr-x root root systemd
drwxr-xr-x root root catalog
-rw-r--r-- root root database
```

Comment: The availability and name of the package depends on your distro. This information appears to be correct for Debian (and thus derived distros like Ubuntu, Mint, etc) but probably not for random others. As another random data point, the tool appears to be installed out of the box on CentOS (based on a quick check with `docker pull centos`) but their `util-linux` package appears to contain something else.

Comment: @tripleee It is this: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/about/ The distro packages containing that might be named differently though. (Its documentation refers to it this way "The namei command is part of the util-linux package and is available from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/ ".)

Comment: My 2 cents: on Arch, `util-linux` is a dependency of `systemd` and so is always installed.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is interested in the full ACL (access list) not included in the normal `ls -l` we can use:

```
   p="/home/marom/downloads/db-derby-10.15.1.3-bin.tar.gz"; while [[ -n "$p" ]]; do getfacl -t  "$p"; p=${p%/*};done; getfacl -t "/"
```

The output is:
Notice added group permissions to `wheel` and GUID flag.

```
# file: /home/marom/downloads/db-derby-10.15.1.3-bin.tar.gz
# owner: marom
# group: marom
# flags: -s-
user::rw-
group::rw-                      #effective:rw-
group:wheel:rw-                 #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--

# file: /home/marom/downloads
# owner: marom
# group: marom
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x

# file: /home/marom
# owner: marom
# group: marom
user::rwx
group::---
other::---

# file: /home
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

# file: /
# owner: root
# group: root
user::r-x
group::r-x
other::r-x
```