# Read Apache access log file from a python CGI script and extract ip addresses real time

Tags: python, linux, access-control

I'm trying to read Apache access log file from a python script and extract ip addresses real time. I'm using python CGI programming. 
I have given 777 permissions.

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root adm 1012822 Jun  5 13:02 /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

This is the code I'm using

```
for line in open('/var/log/apache2/access.log'):
    ip = line.split(' ')[0]
    print ip
```

But following Error is displayed. What is the problem here?

```
 A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.
     /usr/lib/cgi-bin/log.py in ()
          6 form = cgi.FieldStorage()
          7 
    =>    8 for line in open('/var/log/apache2/access.log'):
          9     ip = line.split(' ')[0]
         10     print ip
    line undefined, builtin open = <built-in function open>

    <type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/apache2/access.log'
          args = (13, 'Permission denied')
          errno = 13
          filename = '/var/log/apache2/access.log'
          message = ''
          strerror = 'Permission denied'
```

Comment: Try to run this code when apache service is stopped.

Comment: That's not a Python question at all. Check your SELinux or AppArmor or whatever. Check your `audit` logs.

Comment: You've got world-readable permission on the log file itself, but what about the directories leading up to it? The user needs access to all those as well.

Comment: But I want to detect it while Apache is running

Comment: As @DanielRoseman suggests you should check the permissions of the full path. If you whant to make it complicated you could use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8035563/42580 :)